# Copy an Area into the next empty Row of another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy a certain area into the next empty row of another spreadsheet.
Right now I am only able to copy it to a certain destination.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var source="A3:S3";
 var destination="Historie!B3";
 sheet.getRange(source).copyTo(sheet.getRange(destination));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
function xxx() {
    var reference = 'sheet1!A2'; 
    var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(reference);
    rng.setValue(rng.getValue()+1);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
    var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!A3:S3");
    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Historie");
    var values = source.getValues().filter(function(e) {return e.some(function(f) {return f})});
destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```